# How to handle multiple API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I currently have code that fetches about five API calls at the same time.

Sometimes everything goes successfully, most times it returns a fetch error. Is there a way I can run the API calls without them giving me an error?

```
app.post("/movie/:movieName/",function(req,res) {
    const Title = req.params.movieName
    Promise.all([
        fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + Title + "/videos?=en-us").then(Videos => Videos.json()),
        fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + Title + "?&language=en-US").then(Movies => Movies.json()),
        fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + Title + "/credits?&language=en-US").then(Cast => Cast.json()),
        fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?&language=en-US&page=2").then(Playing => Playing.json()),
        fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + Title + "/similar?&language=en-US").then(Similar => Similar.json()),
    ])
      .then(function(response) {
          const Details = response[1]
          const Video = response[0].results[0]
          const Cast = response[2].cast
          const Similar = response[3].results
          const Playing = response[4].results
          res.render(
              "movie",
              { 
                  Details: Details, 
                  Video: Video, 
                  Cast: Cast, 
                  Similar: Similar, 
                  Playing: Playing 
              }
          )
      });
});
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What have you tried to solve the issue at hand? Where are you getting stuck? What research have you done? Please review the [How to Ask guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Taplar i get a fetch error  reason:ETIMEDOUT

Comment: @esqew am sorry you couldn't get me. I have tried using a catch block but that does not help it gives me a fetch error of  reason:ETIMIEDOUT

Comment: Why did the fetch time out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this as an answer just so I can propose some code that you can run to test out various theories since we don't yet know what the actual issue is.

ETIMEDOUT does not really tell us why you're getting the error.

If this is a major site, it's unlikely that the server is just underperforming and is actually timing out.  It's possible that it's unhappy that you're sending it 5 rapid-fire requests all at once, but it really ought to be giving you a different sort of error.

It's also possible, there's some sort of problem with your network connection between you and this api server.

To rule out the rapid fire requests issue, you can send your request serially, with a short delay between them and see if that changes the issue at all.

```
app.post("/movie/:movieName/", async function(req, res) {
    try {
        const Title = req.params.movieName;

        function fetchCommon(suffix) {
            return fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + suffix).then(r => r.json());
        }

        function delay(t) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(resolve, t);
            });
        }

        const input = [
            Title + "/videos?=en-us",
            Title + "?&language=en-US",
            Title + "?&language=en-US",
            "now_playing?&language=en-US&page=2",
            Title + "/similar?&language=en-US"
        ];
        const results = [];
        const waitTime = 250;

        for (arg of input) {
            let result = await fetchCommon(arg);
            results.push(result);
            await delay(waitTime);
        }
        const Details = response[1];
        const Video = response[0].results[0];
        const Cast = response[2].cast;
        const Similar = response[3].results;
        const Playing = response[4].results;
        res.render(
            "movie", {
                Details,
                Video,
                Cast,
                Similar,
                Playing
            }
        );
    } catch (e) {
        // always send a response, even if there's an error
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Note: This is step #1 of debugging the problem.  The hope is that you learn something from running this code and can then zero in on the actual root cause of the problem.

Comment: @ElohoKennedy - If this fixed your problem, then you can experiment with reducing the `waitTime` (perhaps down to `0`).  You can also indicate to the community that this solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.